# django-bootstrap5 TemplatesSyntaxError

Tags: django, django-templates, django-bootstrap4

I am trying to utilize Django-bootstrap 5 for my form, after creating the form and everything I rendered my template and here is it.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap5 %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <h1>Log In</h1>
  <form method="POST" class="form">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% bootstrap_form form %}
      {% buttons %}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">login</button>
      {% endbuttons %}
      {% endblock bootsrap_form %}
  </form>

</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

urls.py

```
path('login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='account/login.html'),name='login')
```

But when I run the server I got a template syntax error telling me that its expecting an end block meanwhile I have an endblock already, here is the error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /account/login/
Invalid block tag on line 8: 'bootsrap_form', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/login/
Django Version: 3.2.4
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Invalid block tag on line 8: 'bootsrap_form', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

and the code returned in the error interface looks like this:

```
1   {% extends "base.html" %}
2   {% load bootstrap5 %}
3   {% block content %}
4   <div class="container">
5     <h1>Log In</h1>
6     <form method="POST">
7       {% csrf_token %}
8       {% bootsrap_form form%}
9       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Login">
10    </form>
11  
12  </div>
13  
14  {% endblock content %}
```

What I noticed: when I ran the server the first time, I made a typo by writing bootstrap as bootstrap and I fixed it since then, but this error keeps on showing me the first code that I have deleted ever since.
What I did: Since I noticed that, changed the template name in my views to make sure it rendered template not found and re-run the server, But the worst thing is that the same error showed up again not only that It does not acknowledge the correction I made to the template, rather what it does is just retuning the first template I deleted.
Note, I also read the Django-template documentary and it does not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you have substantial differences between the two templates.
This can happen when:

- you use a library which includes some templates: if your installed apps list (in the settings) is not in the right order, the included templates may have precedence.
- you have several `login.html` templates (it may happen) and your view automatically redirects to the wrong one.

Last but not least: `bootstrap5` is sometimes confusing: there is a huge difference between 4 and 5. If you use a `bootstrap5` with a `bootstrap4` inspired template, you will get into endless trouble as nothing will work.